# cd x/y/z command does not work even if I see z with ls command when directory is x/y

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac

I cannot set a folder as a directory even if I see it with ls command. What is the problem?

edit:

```
maccomp:~ user$ cd documents/code
maccomp:code user$ ls
data 
maccomp:code user$ cd documents/code/data
-bash: cd: documents/code/data: No such file or directory
```

Why?

second edit:

```
maccomp:code user$ cd ~/documents/code 
maccomp:code user$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  27 user  staff  864 Nov  6 23:36 data 
maccomp:code user$ ls -ld data
ls: data: No such file or directory
maccomp:code user$ cd data
-bash: cd: data: No such file or directory
```

third edit

```
maccomp:code user$ ls -ldB data\ /
drwxr-xr-x  27 user  staff  864 Nov  6 23:36 data /
maccomp:code user$ ls -lB
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  27 user  staff  864 Nov  6 23:36 data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` directory name ends with a space character, so the name is actually "`data`" (without the "" of course). Unless you really need it like that, it's probably best to rename it by running `mv "data " data`.

If you can't change the name, use `cd "data "`, or `cd data?`, or `cd data\` to change into the directory.